# Rails where query fails when using variable in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can some Rails expert throw some light on this behaviour in Rails 4:

```
>query_string = "agent_id = '1'"
 => "agent_id = '1'"

>Lead.includes('agents').where(query_string).length
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'agent_id' in 'where clause'

>Lead.includes('agents').where(agent_id = '1').length
 Lead Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `leads`.* FROM `leads` WHERE (1)
 LeadsAssignment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `leads_assignments`.* FROM `leads_assignments` WHERE `leads_assignments`.`lead_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Agent Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `agents`.* FROM `agents` WHERE `agents`.`id` IN (1, 2)
 => 5
```

The two queries should be identical.  Why would one fail and the other not?

Thanks!
Charlie

Comment: `Lead.includes('agents').where(agent_id = '1').length` is not even valid syntax and can not work

Comment: It's valid, it's just not doing what you expect. It's making a new variable called `agent_id`, assigning `'1'` to it, then using that to execute `where('1')`...which is valid, it's just going to match every row.

Comment: @gmcnaughton is spot on. This should be offered as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Lead.includes('agents').where(query_string).length
```

This is a valid query which will return you proper result but as you can see the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'agent_id' in 'where clause'
```

You don't have `agent_id` in `leads` table

Whereas

```
Lead.includes('agents').where(agent_id = '1').length
```

This syntax is wrong but the query is returning you some results because `agent_id = '1'` is an assignment operation which returns `'1'` to `where` clause

and the query which executes is

```
 Lead.includes('agents').where(1).length
```

which will return you the `length` of all records in `Lead`

The query should be

```
Lead.includes('agents').where(agent_id: 1).length
```

and you need to add `agent_id` in leads table

Answer (score 5):

As @Andrey pointed out

```
Lead.includes('agents').where(agent_id = '1').length
```

Should be written as:

```
Lead.includes('agents').where(agent_id: 1).length
```

Because `where` is a ruby method and you are passing a ruby hash, where hash's key is the column name and value is the cell's value.

EDIT:

Yes, just noticed the error. 
You don't have `agent_id` column, you have `agents` table, which has a (hopefully) primary key `id`.
So your query should be:

```
Lead.includes('agents').where(agents: { id: 1 }).length
```

Or:

```
Lead.includes('agents').where("agents.id = 1").length
```

Comment: it does not answer the question in any way :)

Comment: `Lead.includes('agents').where(query_string).length`

is valid and should return a dataset, whereas

    `Lead.includes('agents').where(agent_id = '1').length`

is invalid and should raise an `argument of WHERE clause` exception.

You somehow say, that have vice versa working, which makes no sense.

Comment: It would also work if if were `where("agent_id = '1'")`. The query needs to be a string (wrapped in quotes) in order for activerecord to pass it along to MySQL.  As it is now, it's ruby code and not a string, so Ruby evaluates it first.